# Beautiful way to interrupt a loop in Python

Tags: python

Let's say that we have the following code:

```
import time

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            print('STAGE 1')
            time.sleep(1)

            print('STAGE 2')
            time.sleep(0.5)

            for i in range(20):
                print('.')
                time.sleep(0.1)

f = Foo()
f.main_loop()
```

And that we want to pause and resume the `main_loop` somehow. One of the most straightforward way to achieve it would be adding a kind of flag that determines the loop state, for instance:

```
import time

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.is_paused = False

    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            print('STAGE 1')
            time.sleep(1)

            print('STAGE 2')
            time.sleep(0.5)

            for i in range(20):
                while self.is_paused:
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                print('.')
                time.sleep(0.1)

f = Foo()
f.main_loop()
```

Currently, we can pause the loop when it reachs the `for`, but not at the stages 1 and 2. Thus, we should copy and paste the following lines to almost every single line inside the `while` loop...

```
while self.is_paused:
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

So, my question is, **there is a most correct/beatiful way to set up a pause/resume toggle for a loop?**

And, in particular, **there is another way to constantly check the state of a flag?**

Comment: What about `yield` statements?

Comment: Did you intend to do something multithreaded here? None of the code beyond `f.main_loop()` will be reached, because that call doesn't return.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I didn't know anything wbout yield, let's check it

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, sorry. I messed it up. I'm using multithreading in my real code, I just writed the small example quickly without taking that into consideration

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Could you please write a small example?

Comment: Usually the "elegant" way to "constantly check the state of a flag" in a multithreaded context is with [condition objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects).